# Taking a functional derivative

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, probability

I am following the derivation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_entropy_probability_distribution#Proof_in_the_Case_of_Equality_Constraints). I reproduce a smaller part of it here:

Consider the functional

$J(p) = \eta_0\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p(x)dx$

for some probability distribution $p(x)$. It is then stated that

$\frac{\delta J}{\delta p} = \eta_0$.

I'm not sure what exactly happened in the step before. What I think is going on is the following analogue of discrete case. If

$J = \eta_0\sum_i p_i(x)$, I can see that

$\frac{\delta J}{\delta p_j} = \eta_0\sum_i \frac{\partial p_i(x)}{\partial p_j(x)} = \eta_0\sum_i \delta_{ij} = \eta_0$.

Is this what is happening in the continuous case as well? How is the operation $\frac{\delta J}{\delta p}$ defined exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given partial derivatives $\frac{\partial p_i}{\partial p_j}=\delta_i^j$, the discrete labels $i,\,j$ index variables $p_i$. With functional derivatvies we have continuous labels, viz. $\frac{\delta p(x)}{\delta p(y)}=\delta(x-y)$ (note the right-hand side is now a Dirac delta, not a Kronecker delta). So if $\eta$ has at most one argument, we can write $\frac{\delta J}{\delta p(y)}=\eta_0(y)\int_{\Bbb R}\delta(x-y)dx=\eta_0(y)$.

Comment: Thank you. Just to clarify, the meaning of $\frac{\delta J}{\delta p}$ on Wikipedia is what exactly? Is it $\frac{\delta J}{\delta p(y)}$ for specific $y$?

Comment: @user1936752 The meaning follows from the definition I've given, together with $\frac{\delta}{\delta p}$ commuting with integration operators, obeying the product & chain rules etc. The $y$-dependence is needed in general, because e.g. $\frac{\delta}{\delta p(y)}\int_{\Bbb R}p^2(x)dx=2p(y)$ (proof is an exercise). However, you shouldn't think of it as a specific $y$; differentiating the integral with respect to a function gives a function.